# change attribute of a button to submit

Tags: jquery, forms, button, attributes, submit

Please help me to find how to change the attribute of a button to submit using JQuery when button is pressed.

For example, when I press a button with value 'OK', it should change to type 'submit' and value become 'Save'

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$('button[value="OK"]').click(function(){
   $(this).attr({
     type:'submit',
     value: 'Save'
   });
});
```

However, that is ***not a good practice***. You can either use a submit directly or create a new submit button instead of changing the type because browsers may not behave in the similar fashion you might expect.

Comment: Just realized my mistake and deleted my answer.  I'd upvote you but I'm out of votes for the day.

Comment: Good point about this not being a good practice.  I'm wondering why he's changing the type in the first place.  Strange...

Comment: @jmort253: True, I have suggested the alternative which is better, rest is upto OP :)

Comment: another alternative is to use a hidden submit, then hide the OK BUTTON and show SUBMIT when user clicks on OK... one more note - if possible, use an ID for the selector, as $('button[value="OK"]') could be quite wasteful (performance-wise) - so use $('#button_id').click(..,)

Comment: @Smejko: True, lived up to what OP was using in his question :)

Answer (score 0):

======================================================================

### **javascript:**

```
  function btn_onclick(){

      var btn=document.getElementById(button_id');

      btn.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
      btn.setAttribute('value', 'save');

  }
```

======================================================================

### **Jquery:**

```
 function btn_onclick(){

      $('#' + button_id).prop('type', 'submit');
      $('#' + button_id).html('Save');

   }
```

======================================================================

Answer (score 0):

from another very good answer in stackoverflow:

With javascript:

```
 document.getElementsById("OK")[0].type = "button";
```

With jQuery:

```
 $("input[id='OK']").prop("type", "button");
```

And you cant change types of button in Explorer 8 and bellow.

Regards!